# Possible to install all missing modules for a node application?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node app that I just started working with and each time I try to run it, it says there is a missing module.  I've just been using `npm install ...` for each module but after doing about 10 of them I'm wondering if there is a way to have npm pull down all needed modules for a node app without me installing each one manually.  Can it be done?

Comment: you should use https://github.com/imkimchi/ni, It automatically install missing dependencies from package.json comparing all js codes in the project

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, as long as the dependency is listed in `package.json`.

In the directory that contains `package.json`, just type:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 16):

I created an npm module to handle installing missing modules automatically.

[npm-install-missing](https://npmjs.org/package/npm-install-missing)

It will install all app dependencies and sub-dependencies automatically.  This is useful when submodules aren't installed correctly.

Comment: It's even detect dependencies required version!

Comment: When I try this It tells me that I have no missing modules, although when I run npm list It is loaded with missing and unmet dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You can run `npm install yourModule --save` in order to install and automatically update `package.json` with this newly installed module.

So when you run `npm install` a second time it will install every dependecy previously added and you won't need to reinstall every dependency one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script for this.
Place it at the start of your script, and any uninstalled modules will be installed when you run it.

```
(function () {
  var r = require
  require = function (n) {
    try {
      return r(n)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Module "${n}" was not found and will be installed`)
      r('child_process').exec(`npm i ${n}`, function (err, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Module "${n}" could not be installed. Try again or install manually`)
          console.log(body)
          exit(1)
        } else {
          console.log(`Module "${n}" was installed. Will try to require again`)
          try{
            return r(n)
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Module "${n}" could not be required. Please restart the app`)
            console.log(e)
            exit(1)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: this works great, but it fails the first run, because the dependencies are being installed when try to run the rest of the file. how can we wait until your script finishes before begin running the rest of the file?

Comment: @Dat30, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by [@Aminadav Glickshtein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189239/possible-to-install-all-missing-modules-for-a-node-application/21525031#21525031) to create a script of my own that would **synchronously** install the needed modules, because his answer lacks these capabilities.

I needed some help, so I started an SO question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270058/node-cant-find-certain-modules-after-synchronous-install)**. You can read about how this script works there.
The result is as follows:

```
const cp = require('child_process')

const req = async module => {
  try {
    require.resolve(module)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Could not resolve "${module}"\nInstalling`)
    cp.execSync(`npm install ${module}`)
    await setImmediate(() => {})
    console.log(`"${module}" has been installed`)
  }
  console.log(`Requiring "${module}"`)
  try {
    return require(module)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Could not include "${module}". Restart the script`)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

const main = async () => {
  const http    = await req('http')
  const path    = await req('path')
  const fs      = await req('fs')
  const express = await req('express')

  // The rest of the app's code goes here
}

main()
```

And a one-liner (139 characters!). It doesn't globally define `child_modules`, has no last `try-catch` and doesn't log anything in the console:

```
const req=async m=>{let r=require;try{r.resolve(m)}catch(e){r('child_process').execSync('npm i '+m);await setImmediate(()=>{})}return r(m)}

const main = async () => {
  const http    = await req('http')
  const path    = await req('path')
  const fs      = await req('fs')
  const express = await req('express')

  // The rest of the app's code goes here
}

main()
```