# Is there a way to automatically install node.js dependencies from a .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, npm

If I have a foo.js node script, is there a way for me to automatically install all the npm dependencies?

e.g. If foo.js had this:

```
var program = require('commander');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

Is there any npm command or something that I could do that would read foo.js and do 'npm install commander;npm install cheerio'?

Comment: to install the dependencies `automatically` , first of all list them `manually` in `package.json` file and run the `npm install`(sometimes `sudo npm install`) command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to automatically install the required modules for a node.js script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226025/is-it-possible-to-automatically-install-the-required-modules-for-a-node-js-scrip)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

List your dependencies in a [package.json](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html) file. You can then run `npm install` to install all dependencies.

Here's an example of a package.json file. Notice how dependencies are defined:

```
{
  "name": "best-practices",
  "description": "A package using versioning best-practices",
  "author": "Charlie Robbins <charlie@nodejitsu.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "0.x.x",
    "express": "2.3.x",
    "optimist": "0.2.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vows": "0.5.x"
  },
  "engine": "node >= 0.4.1"
}
```

*Source: https://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right/*

Comment: Thank you for the answer and useful link, let me read up on it! I was (naively?) hoping there was a programmatic way to extract the dependencies from the .js file itself. I'll read through the package dependencies link you posted.

Answer (score 9):

There is now a tool that auto-installs required dependencies as you code.

It's called [auto-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

npm-install-peers is a npm package that will detect peers and install them.

Note that you should install it globally